# How can I install visual studio code when blocked?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pip

My school blocks downloads except some things. It doesn't allow installers that modify the device. I was able to download visual studio code as a zip file though and use it. I cannot install modules using pip because it says I need to download visual studio c++ build tools but I can't. How do I make it work?

I could not find a way to download the build tools because it gets blocked.

Comment: I would install Linux onto a USB stick, install everything you need to it, then boot the school PC from the stick.

Answer (score 0):

i will not suggest you to do that without the school permission or at least keep your teacher in your side ;) (team work)   .
**just for educational purpose**

1. Portable Version: Instead of relying on the installer, you can try using the portable version of Visual Studio Code. The portable version does not require installation and can be run directly from a folder. This might bypass the restrictions imposed by your school's network.
2. Online IDEs: Consider using online Integrated Development Environments (IDEs) that do not require any installation or downloads. These web-based IDEs allow you to code and run programs directly from your browser, eliminating the need for local installations.
3. Request Assistance: Reach out to your school's IT department or network administrator and explain your situation. They may be able to provide a solution or grant you temporary access to download and install the necessary tools.
4. Use an External Device: If allowed, you could try using a personal device (such as a laptop or USB drive) that is not subject to the same network restrictions. This would allow you to download and install the required tools without any limitations.

Remember to always adhere to your school's policies and guidelines regarding software usage and network restrictions.

Edit -

as you said that you are unable to install Python packages using pip then there are alternative methods you can try to install packages without relying on these tools.

1.Pre-compiled Binary Packages: Many popular Python packages provide pre-compiled binary packages, which can be installed without the need for compilation. You can search for pre-compiled packages on the Python Package Index (PyPI) or the package's official website. These packages usually have a .whl (wheel) extension. To install a pre-compiled package, you can use the following command:

```
pip install package_name.whl
```

2.Conda: Conda is a package manager that can be used as an alternative to pip. It provides pre-compiled packages and manages dependencies. You can install Conda by following the instructions on the official Anaconda website. Once installed, you can use the conda install command to install packages. For example:

```
conda install package_name
```

3.Manual Installation: (it may feel hard) if you have access to the source code of the package you want to install , you can manually install it by following the instructions provided in the package's documentation. This usually involves downloading the source code, extracting it, and running the installation command. For example:

```
python setup.py install
```

Please note that these alternative methods may not work because of you school's restriction and some packages may have specific dependencies or require compilation.

Comment: We can install stuff it's just the teacher with the codes is not available so teachers can't install some coding softwares for class.

Comment: How can I download c++ build tools or something to download modules

Comment: go with the edit and see if any of these works